# ErrorDocument Not Working

Tags: apache2, amazon-aws, ubuntu

I've been trying to solve this problem, I have a virtual machine with the same setup as my production server. The **ErrorDocument line in 000-default.conf** works on my VM, however it doesn't work on my production server.

The two seemingly different points are a) The **production server has a security certificate** and b) the 000-default.conf on the production server has **mod_rewrite** enabled while it's not being used, it is a difference.

I've disabled mod_rewrite to see what would happen, which has changed nothing. All documents

I have the default folder set (/var/www/html) and the only changes I've made to the 000-default.conf are as followed:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error_pages/50x.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error_pages/50x.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error_pages/50x.html
ErrorDocument 504 /error_pages/50x.html

<Files "404.html">
    <If "-z %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}">
        RedirectMatch 404 ^/404.html$
    </If>
</Files>

<Files "50x.html">
    <If "-z %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}">
        RedirectMatch 404 ^/50x.html$
    </If>
</Files>
```

mod rewrite portion:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.website.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

I'm not sure if this would be a cause either, however, my certificate is only valid for the www, and not the bare URL.

Not sure where to go from here, the server displays the default apache error page.

Comment: What do you see instead of your 404 error document? That mod_rewrite portion is presumably in the VirtualHost for port 80? (Taken out of context that mod_rewrite portion is a bit meaningless.)

Comment: It shows the default error page (apache 404 error for example). Yep, port 80, I posted only what was changed from the default 000-default.conf.

Comment: "It shows the default error page" - and there is no additional note that states, "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."?  What happens when you try to access the 404 error document directly - what status code is returned? Although the pattern `^/404.html$` would not seem to match, since your error document appears to be located at `/error_pages/404.html`?

Comment: I scrutinized the page further, and noticed it said this:

Comment: `Not Found The requested URL /lkjlkj was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.website.com Port 443` **I forgot that since I'm using certificates that I'm not on port 80 for the production server, rather I'm on port 443**. I modified the 000-default.conf virtual host to port 443, however there was no change after restarting the server. To answer what happens when I try to access the error pages, I can open them, even when modifying the 000-default.conf to /error_pages/xxx.html.

Comment: "I can open them" - what HTTP status code are you seeing in the network traffic. It should be 404 if your `RedirectMatch` directive is being processed, otherwise a 200 OK.

Comment: It shows a 200 OK code when directly accessing my custom 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to w3dk's questions I was able to work through why my page re-directs weren't working.

I was using let's encrypt for my security certificate, and because of (or perhaps my lack of knowledge), it created a new .conf file with the lines to load the ssl certificates (000-default-le-ssl.conf) which took precedent over the original default.conf.

When I modified this new .conf file everything worked correctly.